# Dual Boot Windows and Ubuntu at the same time

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot

I just recently installed Windows 10 alongside a computer that originally had only Ubuntu. Each OS is stored on its own SSD and by default I have Ubuntu boot as the default OS.

The question that I have, is there an easier way for me to switch between operating systems without having to reboot the computer every time I want to use a different one? Can I make one OS sleep while using the other OS? I am using Ubuntu as my primary day-to-day stuff, and I am using Windows for when I feel like playing a game.

On my Ubuntu computer I have Plex Media Server, so if I want to watch any movies/tv shows that I have stored on it I need to have my Ubuntu OS active.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: not unless one is a VM running inside the other.

Comment: Not sure if this affects your comment, but I don't need to use them side-by-side, just use one for an hour or two then switch to the other, and vise versa where I would physically only be interacting with one OS at a time.

Comment: You would have to restart your system to accomplish what you want but you don’t want to do that so your stuck between impossible and a hard place.

Comment: I would follow Tetsujin's advice.  Within the Super User realm, we see a **lot** of questions from people who encounter problems with their Windows/Linux dual-boot configurations.  On the other hand, we very rarely hear about any type of problems from someone running a VM inside of Hyper-V or VirtualBox.

Comment: The only issue with a VM is that Linux is my primary OS and games don't run well in a VM and the other way around seems pointless since windows isn't my primary OS.

Comment: Then you're in rock/hard place territory, because there's no other way to "live swap" OSes.

Answer (score 0):

There are options.

1. Run Windows as a VM. Windows as you need media performance on Linux.
2. Acquire another box for Windows and use a good quality KVM switch to jump between them.